Two digits in one
Here is a digit:

However, it is, at the same time, another digit.
How can it be?

It's also:

 The digit 1

Indeed,

 If you take the 3D representation of 2 and apply a 90° rotation to it, it becomes a 1, see for yourself:

 

I have no specific way of knowing if this is in fact the intended answer but it fits with the geometry tag and, quite literally, lateral thinking. If it's not, well there is only 7 digits left to find an explanation for.

It's also the digit...

 5!


 
 (If you lean back and squint at it hard enough...)


It's quite far from the correct answer. I added a relevant tag.

@webadventurer Yes I assumed as much -- initially only having [tag:lateral-thinking] made somewhat facetious answers such as this one plausible. I see you've added [tag:geometry] now, should the puzzle also have [tag:mathematics] too?

No, [tag:mathematics] tag is not needed here.
